# Excel VBA to Extract data from PowerPoint

Tags: excel, vba

I have this challenge to create a macro to extract data from ppt.
I need to extract the data from tables in a ppt and paste them into Excel.
I can extract data and paste it into Excel, but the tables are printing one below the other, like this:

[image: Current Excel output]

I want the tables to to printed like this:
[image: Desired Excel output]

The below image is from ppt how the tables are placed in ppt,
in similar way the tables need to be printed in the Excel spreadsheet:

[image: Powerpoint layout of tables]

I tried this:

```
Sub ExportToExcelSheet()

'Declare PPT variables
     Dim pptPres As Presentation
     Dim pptSlide As Slide
     Dim pptShape As Shape
     Dim pptPlaceholder As PlaceholderFormat
     Dim pptTable As Table
'Declare Excel variables
     Dim xlApp As Excel. Application
     Dim xlBook As Excel. Workbook
     Dim xlSheet As Excel. Worksheet
     Dim xlRange As Excel.Range

'Access the active presentation
     Set pptPres = Application.ActivePresentation

On Error Resume Next

     Set xlApp = GetObject(, "EXCEL.Application")
     If Err.Number = 429 Then
         Err.Clear
         Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
         xlApp.Visible = True
         Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
         Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets.Add
     End If

     Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks("Extract.xlsx")
     Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

     For Each pptSlide In pptPres.Slides
        For Each pptShape In pptSlide.Shapes
           If pptShape.Type = msoTable Then
              Set pptTable = pptShape.Table
              pptShape.Copy
              Set xlRange = xlSheet.Range("A100").End(xlUp)
              If xlRange.Address <> "$A$1" Then
                  Set xlRange = xlRange.Offset(3, 0)
              End If
              xlSheet.Paste Destination:=xlRange
           End If
         Next
     Next

       xlSheet.Columns.Range("A1").ColumnWidth = 5
       xlSheet.Columns.Range("B1").ColumnWidth = 25
       xlSheet.Rows.RowHeight = 20
End Sub
```

Comment: You worked out how to extract tables from PPT but can't work out how to position them? I suggest you post your code.

Comment: Yes i just need to position them similar to ppt table positions, its just like flow diagram one table after another

Comment: Is there anything unique about the shapes/tables in powerpoint that define if the are a sub station or not? Is it inserted into Excel as an image or does it paste as text in a table format?

Comment: No the tables from ppt are inserted as texts in excel or just copy the tables from ppt and paste it into excel

Comment: and you already have code that does this so far? You'll need to post it

Comment: i already posted the code in main question

Comment: So you did. First thing you need to do is be able to recognise the word "Sub" in the ppt table. Can you do that?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i am not getting what actually you are telling

Comment: oh i got it now

Answer (score 0):

Because `xlRange` is defined by searching the last used cell in `Column A`, you are only pasting to `Column A` and thus, your current output is one after the other down this column.

You can keep it this way and then reposition each table after they are in Excel by serching each title for `"Sub*"` and if found put it on row (say) 10 otherwise using a similar method to your last row, find the last column and offset it say, 3 columns to the right.

Something like this AFTER your existing for loop...

```
    Dim RowCounter As Long
    Dim BottomRowOfTable As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim MyArray As Variant
    For RowCounter = 1 To xlRange    'You can reuse this as the last destination which would be the last header row in the list you pasted.
        With xlSheet
            If .Cells(RowCounter, 1).Value Like "Sub*" Then
                BottomRowOfTable = .Cells(RowCounter, 1).End(xlDown).Row
                LastColumn = .Cells(8, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                MyArray = .Range(.Cells(RowCounter, 1), .Cells(BottomRowOfTable, 1)).Value
                .Range(.Cells(8, LastColumn + 2).Address).Resize(UBound(MyArray)).Value = MyArray
                .Range(.Cells(RowCounter, 1), .Cells(BottomRowOfTable, 1)).Clear
            ElseIf .Cells(RowCounter, 1).Value Like "Station*" Then
                BottomRowOfTable = .Cells(RowCounter, 1).End(xlDown).Row
                LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                MyArray = .Range(.Cells(RowCounter, 1), .Cells(BottomRowOfTable, 1)).Value
                .Range(.Cells(1, LastColumn + 2).Address).Resize(UBound(MyArray)).Value = MyArray
                .Range(.Cells(RowCounter, 1), .Cells(BottomRowOfTable, 1)).Clear
            End If
        End With
    Next RowCounter
```

You will probably need to change some of the cell references so it targets the right cell to find the title and/or move each table to the correct location.

I also did not test with formatting per your current output to Excel.

I think there is probably a cleaner way to do this but this method can achieve your goal.

Comment: After which for loop i have to add this, i am getting TYPE MISMATCH Error on line, For RowCounter = 1 to xlRange

Comment: My appologies,  the error is because the variable is a range but the loop needs a long. Try `xlRange.Row` instead.

Comment: hi @Samuel Everson i am getting this error, at this line .Range(.Cells(RowCounter, 1), .Cells(BottomRowOfTable, 1)).Clear (If statement line), And at this line .Range(.Cells(RowCounter, 1), .Cells(BottomRowOfTable, 1)).Clear (Else if statement line) and its not properly pasting in excel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67223968/powerpoint-to-excel-using-powerpoint-vba    this link provides full explanation about issue i am facing

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, you will need to edit the cell references to target your actual data ranges - the `.Cells()` references should point to the cells your data is in. It looks like the first table is in `Range("A1:B5")` which would look like `.Range(.Cells(1,1),.Cells(5,2))` for example.

Comment: @ Samuel Everson    your code is working somewhat 80% but its not printing the data from 2nd column of the ppt tables it is printing the numbers from 1st column of ppt tables to excel but not the data from 2nd column of ppt tables, the tables are positioning correctly but printing the data from 2nd column is facing issue, and is it possible to print the arrows also in the same way as in ppt.        Thank you for your help

Comment: Should be something like `.Range(.Cells(1, LastColumn + 2).Address).Resize(UBound(MyArray),2).Value = MyArray`