# Powerpoint to excel using Powerpoint VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos, powerpoint

I tried this macro to copy contents from ppt to excel sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExtracttableData()
    'Declare PPT variables
    Dim pptPres As Presentation
    Dim pptSlide As Slide
    Dim pptShape As Shape
    Dim pptPlaceholder As PlaceholderFormat
    Dim pptTable As Table
    
    'Declare Excel variables
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlRange As Excel.Range
    Dim xlRange2 As Excel.Range
        
    Dim rowCounter As Long
    Dim bottomRowoftable As Long
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    Dim myArray As Variant
    
    'Access the active presentation
    Set pptPres = Application.ActivePresentation
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "EXCEL.Application")
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
        Err.Clear
        Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
        xlApp.Visible = True
    End If
        
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks("Book1.xlsx")
    Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        
    For Each pptSlide In pptPres.Slides
        For Each pptShape In pptSlide.Shapes
            If pptShape.Type = msoTable Then
                Set pptTable = pptShape.Table
                pptShape.Copy
                Set xlRange = xlSheet.Range("A100").End(xlUp)
                If xlRange.Address <> "$A$1" Then
                    Set xlRange = xlRange.Offset(3, 0)
                End If
                xlSheet.Paste Destination:=xlRange
            End If
        Next
    Next
        
    For rowCounter = 1 To xlRange.Row
        With xlSheet
            If .Cells(rowCounter, 1).Value Like "Sub*" Then
                bottomRowoftable = .Cells(rowCounter, 1).End(xlDown).Row
                lastColumn = .Cells(8, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                myArray = .Range(.Cells(rowCounter, 1), .Cells(bottomRowoftable, 1)).Value
                .Range(.Cells(8, lastColumn + 2).Address).Resize(UBound(myArray)).Value = myArray
                .Range(.Cells(rowCounter, 1), .Cells(bottomRowoftable, 1)).Clear                        
            ElseIf .Cells(rowCounter, 1).Value Like "Station*" Then
                bottomRowoftable = .Cells(rowCounter, 1).End(xlDown).Row
                lastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                myArray = .Range(.Cells(rowCounter, 1), .Cells(bottomRowoftable, 1)).Value
                .Range(.Cells(1, lastColumn + 2).Address).Resize(UBound(myArray)).Value = myArray
                .Range(.Cells(rowCounter, 1), .Cells(bottomRowoftable, 1)).Clear                           
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

If I comment the lines

```
.Range(.Cells(rowCounter, 1), .Cells(bottomRowoftable, 1)).Clear ' (if statement line)
.Range(.Cells(rowCounter, 1), .Cells(bottomRowoftable, 1)).Clear ' (Else if statement line)
```

I get this output but not complete

[image]

if i dont comment those two lines i get this error

[image]

[image]

The macro doing `70%` of work but its not printing the text from `2nd` column of every table

[image]

This entire thing (tables and text) must be copied to excel spread sheet
it must be copied like tables named **stations** are printed first one after the other (to right or left not below) then tables named **substations** printed below station tables one after another

Comment: Please don't re-post the same question where you have another one unresolved on the same topic/tasks. It's better practice to edit your existing question where applicable, or mark an answer as accepted and then post a new question about the specific issue from the new code.  [Excel VBA to Extract data from PowerPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67212019/excel-vba-to-extract-data-from-powerpoint)

Comment: `if i dont comment those two lines i get this error` Let me explain this error with an example. Let's say your range is from `A1:A10` out of which `A5:A8` is merged. If you clear the entire range ``A1:A10`` then you will not get the error becuase the entire merged cells are covered in that range but if you try to clear say `A1:A6` then you will get the error that you are getting because  `A7:A8` have been exlcuded :)

Comment: Actually when it comes to using VBA, then merged cells soon or later become a pain in the … Merged cells are evil. If you can, stay away from merged cells and use [Center Across Selection](https://officemastery.com/_merge-and-centre-better-alternative/) instead. This way you don't run into all the odd difficulties that come with merged cells.